# Error: unable to open database "db/development.sqlite3": unable to open database file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

Since I started developing my application, I have used SQLite3. It has been working well, and I have filled my tables with data. Suddenly the terminal window which I used for querying the database stopped responding. I had an open SQLite3 terminal window when running a bundle install. Maybe that was causing the problems? I don't know, because I didn't try to use the terminal window until some hours later.

Now, when I run sqlite3 -line db/development.sqlite3, the usual things happen, but when I try to do a query or write ".tables", I get the error message shown in the title of this post. The strange thing is that querying the database from the application works well. Since the data obviously are intact, is there a way to back up these before I try to remove SQLite and install it again? How do I remove SQLite?

I tried bundle update SQLite3 and got no errors, but when I run sqlite3 -line db/development.sqlite3, the version reported is 3.7.7, and not 3.7.10 which is the newest version.

I use Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: "Removing" SQLite shouldn't affect any SQLite databases directly.  You just won't be able to load them if you don't have the SQLite library available.  Re-install SQLite to your hearts content, it has no knowledge of your individual SQLite database files.

Comment: Read this: http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html

Comment: Thank's! I uninstalled it with sudo bundle uninstall SQLite3 and then installed it again, but it didn't help. :-(

Comment: I installed Sqliteman, which is a graphical manager for SQLite for linux. I can do all I want with the database from there (it's working!). Sqliteman seems to be a nice tool, even though I would prefer to be able to use the terminal.